# jQuery tabs: Set css of tab navigation button by index

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to set the css of one tab navigation button programmaticaly. The index of the tab should be a variable.

Use case: Setting a button to color red when it content has changed ascync.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Give your tab divs ids as `tab-0`, `tab-1`, `tab-2`, etc; the following should work -

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); // retrieve here or pass it to function.

$("#tab-" + selected ).addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: Thanx, but that would apply style to the content div. I want to apply style to one navigation button only.

Comment: then as the tab example says.. you need to put style to `UL` and `LI` ( .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide ) as mentioned in official example http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/